# Not able to always set toolbar at bottom

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

I have added a toolbar on my storyboard and set its outlet also. Now when I come to my view with the toolbar, in the `viewDidLoad` of that view I have written this...

```
postToolBar.removeFromSuperview()
contributeTextView.inputAccessoryView = postToolBar
```

Because of this, when I come to the view and tap on the textview I have there named `contributeTextView`, the keyboard comes up with the toolbar fixed on top like so..

[image]

Now when I tap outside the textview, the keyboard goes down and so does the toolbar with it. How do I always fix the toolbar at the bottom itself..? The toolbar should also come up with the keyboard and when the keyboard goes down, it should still be fixed at the bottom. How can I achieve that..?

Comment: add two toolbars one as  inputAccessoryView as you are doing now, and another add to the bottom of the controller's view.

Comment: ok @vivekDas Thanks...please put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this trick:- Add two toolbars one as `inputAccessoryView` as you are doing now, and another add to the bottom of the controller's view. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

you could observer the keyboard notification, for example:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

then in the selector, change the toolbar frame related to the keyboard, like:

```
@objc private func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
              var frame = toolBar.frame
              frame.origin.y = keyboardFrame.origin.y - frame.size.height
              toolBar.frame = frame
        }
  }
```

this should be work